# I want to Execute the python method by clicking on Html Button....in my django project

Tags: python, html, django

**NoReverseMatch at /studentUpdate/
Reverse for 'student_update' not found. 'student_update' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

**I am explaining the code very simply**

Here is the code for the **html** button named **update** at the end of the form by clicking on that I want to execute python method called **student_update**

```
    <form id="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'students' %}">

                    {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label >Student ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="sid" required="required" class="form-control"/> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Department:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="department" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Section:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="section" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Year:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="year" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button name="save_book" id="save_book" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'student_update' %}">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save">
</span>
                            Update

                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

**Here is my url.py file**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from django.urls import path, re_path
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index$', views.index),
    url(r'^student_update/(\d+)/$', views.student_update, name="updt_stud")
]
```

**Finally Here is my views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db.models import Sum
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from library.models import Book, Category, Student, Borrow
from django.template import loader 

def student_update(request):
    return redirect('/students')     #I want my code to reach here
```

Comment: You make an AJAX request to the given view.

Comment: I am new in this...plz tell me how to make this Ajax request

Comment: Ajax call is usually used when you don't want to reload your page. Your work can be done without ajax call, check my solution.

Comment: The error you are getting for that AJAX is not the solution.

Comment: its a Django framework bro..I wanted to execute the python method by simply clicking on the html button that's it in the <script> tag I had written my ajax code where I had collected all the entries from the textboxes and then I had sent it to the server after clicking on the button and then in my views.py file I had defined a method where I had collected all these entries and then updated the record that's it

Comment: And yes sure I will check your solution as well

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the url.py  file, the url you have mentioned for the **student_update** is with the name for the url as :**updt_stud**

But while calling the url in the html file you are calling the url by name : **student_update** because which django didn't got to know to go so change it.

Moreover in the url you also have to pass arguments, its because the way you have defined the url for student update.

I hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick="location.href='{% url 'updt_stud' %}'"` in `<button></button>`, and 
`url(r'^student_update/(\d+)/$', views.student_update, name="updt_stud")`, for calling function from button always put the `name="updt_stud"` in `location.href` that you define in `url`. and in `form` tag `action = "/student_update"`, that `action` will match on `url` regex that you define in `url` `r'^student_update/(\d+)/$'`.

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action = "/student_update">
```

and

```
<button name="save_book" id="save_book" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='{% url 'updt_stud' %}'">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save">
</span> Update
</button>
```

In views.py
Add

```
 return render(request, 'new_page.html')
```

Or any html page you want to render.

You can do with `return redirect` try both one by one.